# When a conditional stochastic sequence is convergent, what can we say about the non-conditional one?

Tags: convergence-divergence, stochastic-processes, stochastic-analysis

I have shown that the stochastic sequence of the norm of the gradient converges to zero with the probability one (w.p.1) under some conditions on the function $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$, i.e.,
$$
\|\nabla f(X_k) \|_2^2 \vert  X_{k-1}\to 0 \text{ w.p.1}
$$
where
$X_{k+1}=X_k-\gamma g(X_k, \xi_k)$, $g(X_k, \xi_k)$ is the stochastic approximation of the actual gradient that makes the sequence of $(X_k)$ and $(\nabla f(X_k) \|_2^2 \vert  X_{k-1})$ random. According to $X_{k+1}=X_k-\gamma g(X_k, \xi_k)$ to calculate $X_{k+1}$ one should have $X_{k}$, which is a random quantity from the previous step. Therefore, we write $\|\nabla f(X_k) \|_2^2 \vert  X_{k-1}$ for the $k$-th step which indicates $X_k$ is given.

**Question**

Knowing $\|\nabla f(X_k) \|_2^2 \vert  X_{k-1}\to 0 \text{ w.p.1}$, what can we say about $\|\nabla f(X_k) \|_2^2 \to 0 \text{ w.p.1}$ that does not include $X_{k-1}$? Basically, I do not know how I should think about not having $X_k$ because currently this stochastic process is a Markov process.

Comment: Unless $X_k$ converges to 0 it seems to me that  this is always the case, am I missing something here ?

Comment: @TheBridge: I had $X_k$ instead of  $X_{k-1}$. I edited my statement. Can you check it again.

Comment: What is the meaning of $||\nabla f(X_k)||_2^2|X_{k-1}$ and how is it different from $||\nabla f(X_k)||_2^2$?  In general, for random variables $X$ and $Y$ there is no such thing as $X|Y$ but there is $E[X|Y]$, which is a conditional expectation of $X$ given $Y$ (not an expectation of some unusual object called $X|Y$).

Comment: @Michael: That notation means that $X_k$ that is used to calculate $\|\nabla f(X_k)\|$ uses $X_{k-1}$. In essence, the random variable in the $k$-th step is dependent on the random variable in the previous step.

Comment: Then, there is no difference between $||\nabla f(X_k)||_2$ and $||\nabla f(X_k)||_2 | X_{k-1}$ (except the latter notation is more awkward).  So your question amounts to "Knowing $||\nabla f(X_k)||$ converges to 0 with prob 1, is it true that  $||\nabla f(X_k)||$ converges to 0 with prob 1?"

Comment: @Michael: yes but conditionally.

Comment: Your statement "but conditionally" has no meaning here. A random variable $X$ is a random variable $X$ regardless of the existence of other random variables that may be dependent on $X$.  The kind of "conditional convergence" that you are describing is not something that exists within the world of probability theory.  Convergence of conditional expectations may be the closest match to what you are describing. Or perhaps convergence for outcomes $\omega$ in a certain event $A\subseteq \Omega$.